# Rails AbstractController::DoubleRenderError despite returning a redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My Rails app is throwing a `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError`.  You can see my controller action below, it does include multiple render and/or redirects, however, I've read and found that doing it with a return should negate this exception.

Here is my controller action:

```
def load
  redirect_to login and return if @current_login == nil

  render template: 'app' and return if @current_login
end
```

I've verified that `@current_login` is `nil`, meaning it should redirect and return.

Answer (score 1):

Changing `redirect_to login` to `redirect_to '/login'` did the trick.

I had a controller action `login` in the same controller as the `load` action, so it was calling the `login` action, which had a `render` call in it...

Hopefully someone runs into the same coincidence and this helps them.